# Create MPEG-2 Transfer Stream with AVFoundation

Tags: avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm attempting to create a properly formatted video file for use in Apple's HTTP Live Streaming. Here is the code that creates the file:

```
// Init the device inputs
AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *newAudioInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self audioDevice] error:nil];

// Create session
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
self.session = newCaptureSession;

// Add inputs and output to the capture session
if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newVideoInput]) {
    [newCaptureSession addInput:newVideoInput];
}
if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newAudioInput]) {
    [newCaptureSession addInput:newAudioInput];
}

// Setup the output
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
if ([self.session canAddOutput:aMovieFileOutput])
    [self.session addOutput:aMovieFileOutput];

aMovieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.f, 1);

// Begin recording
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [self.captureOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:[self calculateVideoOrientation]];

[aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self nextOutputURL] recordingDelegate:self];
```

The `[self nextOutputURL]` returns a valid `NSURL`, the file is successfully saved to disk and I can open and view the file in VLC and QuickTime. The video format as viewed in VLC is 'avc1' which I gather is [the same as H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Overview). The video format as viewed in QuickTime is H.264. The extension on the file is, of course, .ts.

It appears that I'm doing everything correctly, yet when I try and validate my HTTP Live stream with `mediastreamvalidator`, I get the following error:

```
http://imac.local.:2020/fileSequence000.ts:
ERROR: (-12971) failed to parse segment as either an MPEG-2 TS or an ES
```

Anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given code doesn't generate a MPEG-2 Transport Stream, rather, it generates a standard MPEG-4 file, but with a .ts extension. VLC and QuickTime will both recognize the file and are able to play it, but mediastreamvalidator correctly notes that it is not an MPEG-2 TS. A quick way to check if the generated file is a MPEG-2 TS is to look at the first byte. If it is not 0x47, then it won't be a MPEG-2 TS.